# L1 minimization linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

So suppose we want to minimize the sum of the absolute errors $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m |b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|$ with respect to $x_k$ where $k=1,...,n$

So to formulate this as a linear programming problem, we state

Minimize $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m y_i$

subject to: $y_i$ $\ge$ $|b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|$ for $i=1,...,m$

and the restrictions on $y_i \ge 0$

My question is why in the "subject to" line, we cannot use the equality constraint instead? i.e. subject to: $y_i$ $=$ $|b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|$ for $i=1,...,m$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because neither $y_i\ge|b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|$ nor $y_i=|b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|$ give you an LP problem (due to the absolute value). To finish conversion to LP one has to write
$$
y_i\ge|b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j|\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
-y_i\le b_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\le y_i
$$
and in the last condition it is *a priori* unclear what inequality becomes equality.

P.S. Condition $y_i\ge 0$ is unnecessary, it is always true if $y_i\ge|...|$.

Comment: So it's because we don't know which inequality (if any) is actually an equality, right?

Comment: Yes, any equality would be an overly constrained condition on $x$ variable. One of those two becomes equality for every $i$ at the optimal $x$, but you just do not know which one.

Comment: Thanks ! 
Much appreciated.