# L1 minimization problem with nested sums as LP problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I've been trying to solve this problem but I have an issue with the fact that there is a sum under each absolute value. I'm trying to convert this minimization problem (with respect to $x, y_1, \dots,y_n$)

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m} \left| x - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left| y_j - a_{ij} \right|  \right|
$$

to a linear programming problem. It's similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388701/l1-minimization-linear-programming?rq=1), however that problem hasn't got the nested sums.

Does it suffice to just do the same substitution as in the linked question or should I make other substitutions and constraints as well?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert this to a linear program. The objective function is not convex (consider the special case $m = n = x = a_{11} = 1$, draw the function and you'll see). You cannot use epigraph models when the expression you outer bound enters in a nonconvex fashion (which the inner absolute value does).

EDIT: Giving a more complete example which shows the failure of the LP proposed in another answer. Assume $a = (2,0,-1)$. An optimal solution to this is $x = y = 1$ (it is not unique) with objective value 1. An optimal solution to a flawed LP model would be $x=2, y=0, z = (0,0,0), \omega = (2,2,2)$. The LP objective is thus $0$, but if you plug the solution $x = 2, y = 0$ into the original nonlinear objective, it has objective value 3. In other words, the LP is incorrect. Here is a MATLAB/YALMIP model to reproduce example

```
a = [2;0;-1];
sdpvar x y
Objective = sum(abs(x - abs(y-a)));
optimize([],Objective)
[value(x) value(y) value(Objective)]

z = sdpvar(3,1);
w = sdpvar(3,1);
Model = [-z <= x - w <= z, -w <= a-y <= w];
optimize(Model,sum(z))
[value(x) value(y) value(sum(z)) value(Objective)]
```

Comment: hmmm. interesting point. It is not convex, but it is piecewise linear. This should not be a problem.

Comment: In don't see a problem. Replace $\min |x - |y-a||$ by the relaxed problem $\min z$ s.t. $-z \leq x - |y-a| \leq z$. The constraint is feasible for $z \geq 0$. Hence $z = 0$ is the minimum. The constraint gives $\{ (x,y) : x = |y-a| \}$ as the solution set (of course..).

Comment: The outer absolute value which you reason about here is not the problem. The problem is when you now take the absolute value which you now have in the double-sided inequality (and thus is nonconvex) and try to introduce an upper bound epigraph model of those terms. The final model will not be tight when you minimize z, in the general case.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, as pointed out by Johan Löfberg, this is not a convex function, so it is vain to search for a pure linear program. Therefore, the following **does not work** in the general case :

**Step 1:**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m z_i
$$
subject to
$$
x-\sum_{j=1}^n|y_j-a_{ij}| \le z_i\\
-x+\sum_{j=1}^n|y_j-a_{ij}| \le z_i
$$

**Step 2:**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m z_i
$$
subject to
$$
x-\sum_{j=1}^n \omega_{ij} \le z_i\\
-x+\sum_{j=1}^n \omega_{ij} \le z_i\\
y_j-a_{ij} \le \omega_{ij}\\
-y_j+a_{ij} \le \omega_{ij}\\
$$

I am convinced however that a MILP very close to the above program should do the trick. Still working on it, trying to use binaries to ensure tightness.

Comment: No, you cannot apply an epigraph reformulation on the inner absolute values here. Applying a convex non-monotonic function on a concave non-monotonic function will not necessarily lead to a convex function, and epigraphs are not valid

Comment: @JohanLöfberg how do you prove his 'step 2' LP doesn't solve the problem ?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg so what is the final verdict? Is this answer valid or not?

Comment: JohanLofberg pointed out the fact that the function isn't convex, therefore it is unlikely that a pure linear program does the trick. However, I cannot find where the error is in my solution. Perhaps you should consider opening a bounty for the question to receive more attention. It's a great question!

Comment: The answer is not correct. The epigraphs used to model the inner (nonconvexely appearing) absolute values will not yield correct bounds.

Comment: Added a simple example in my example to show a failing example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have edited my answer accordingly with a model that works for your specific example, but I would be reassured if you or someone could validate it!